# How to pass a logical volume form numpy to itk for saving to a nrrd file?

Tags: python, numpy, itk

I'm trying to save a `numpy` volume to an `NRRD` file format using `itk`, to use it later with `Matlab`, and I want export the file in a `Boolean` or `logical` datatype if that's possible.

The operation works great with `int16` datatype (*but the resultant file is large*):

```py
itkVol = itk.GetImageFromArray(npVol.astype(np.int16))
imageType = itk.Image[itk.SS, 3]

writerType = itk.ImageFileWriter[imageType]
writer = writerType.New()
writer.SetFileName('/home/user/Desktop/test.nrrd')
writer.SetInput(itkVol)
writer.Update()
```

The original type of `npVol` (the `numpy` 3D array) is `float64`, my problem is that I didn't know how save it is `logical` or `bool` datatype to save memory (*I have to export many of them and they are large files*).

I tried casting the type to a `bool` type and pass it to the `ImageFileWriter()` in `itk` but I got an error:

here is the code:

```py
itkVol = itk.GetImageFromArray(npVol.astype(np.bool))
imageType = itk.Image[itk.B, 3]
```

and here is the error:

```
TemplateTypeError: itk.ImageFileWriter is not wrapped for input type `itk.Image[itk.B,3]`.
```

The error messages are pretty straightforward about `ImageFileWriter()` not supporting such a type, and it gave me the list of supported input types (and non of them is `logical` or of type `bool`):

```
Supported input types:

itk.Image[itk.UC,2]
itk.Image[itk.UC,3]
itk.Image[itk.RGBPixel[itk.UC],2]
itk.Image[itk.RGBPixel[itk.UC],3]
itk.Image[itk.RGBAPixel[itk.UC],2]
itk.Image[itk.RGBAPixel[itk.UC],3]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,2],2]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,2],3]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,3],2]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,3],3]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,4],2]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,4],3]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,2],2]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,2],3]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,3],2]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,3],3]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,4],2]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,4],3]
itk.Image[itk.SS,2]
itk.Image[itk.SS,3]
itk.Image[itk.US,2]
itk.Image[itk.US,3]
itk.Image[itk.F,2]
itk.Image[itk.F,3]
itk.Image[itk.complex[itk.F],2]
itk.Image[itk.complex[itk.F],3]
itk.VectorImage[itk.SS,2]
itk.VectorImage[itk.UC,2]
itk.VectorImage[itk.US,2]
itk.VectorImage[itk.F,2]
itk.VectorImage[itk.SS,3]
itk.VectorImage[itk.UC,3]
itk.VectorImage[itk.US,3]
itk.VectorImage[itk.F,3]
```

**How can I do it?**

PS: *I'm new to both python and itk*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image of `bool`s is frequently needed for binary masks, but all real-world solutions I have seen is using an integral type. 0=false, nonzero=true, usually in 8-bit unsigned int. NumPy's name for it might be uint8, and ITK's name for it is UC (unsigned char). Getting around this is hard.

But what could be easily accomplished is to compress the output file by `writer.SetUseCompression(True)` or `writer.UseCompressionOn()`. And if your "true" value is consistent (e.g. always 1 or always 255), these files should compress well. If your image is a binary label map, you can expect compression down to about 1%-2% of their original size.

Comment: yes my "true" value is consistent and I did as you mentioned but I got an error: AttributeError: 'itkImageFileWriterIUC3' object has no attribute 'SetCompressionOn'.

Comment: Ok, I found it in the documentation it's SetUseCompression(True), and it working great from 34Mb to 152kb, thank you